# Exporting logs out of loganalaysis ibm cloud

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, log-analysis

Is there a way to export logs out of IBM Cloud? Mainly activity logs which come from Activity Tracker. Also, does anyone know where these logs are stored? I can only view them inside Kibana but dont see any storage associated with it.

I tried

```
ibmcloud logging log-show but it errors out as: 
read: connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must choose a premium plan to make API calls and export the logs from Activity Tracker[image]

Once you create the Activity Tracker service, you can use the CLI to export the logs by creating a session

```
ibmcloud at session help create                                                                                                           
NAME:
   bx at session create - Create a new session
USAGE:
   bx at session create [command options] [arguments...]

OPTIONS:
   --start value, -s value        start date, in format 2006-01-02 (default: "2018-11-09")
   --end value, -e value          end date, in format 2006-01-02 (default: "2018-11-22")
   --at-account-level, -a         include entire account (default: current space only)
   -T value, --search-time value  Specify search time with the hour of one day, the valid value is 0-23
   --json                         output in JSON format
```

Eg., `ibmcloud at session create -s 2018-11-21 -e 2018-11-22 --json`

Once the session is created, it returns a session id.

You can download the logs using this command

```
ibmcloud at download -o events.log <SESSION_ID>
```

For more details on downloading the events, refer [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker/reference/at_cli_cloud.html#download)

You can also make a [REST API call](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker/how-to/manage_events_api/downloading_events_api.html#downloading_events_api) to download the events

**Update:** Reading through the documentation in-depth, I found out where the data is stored.

> The Activity Tracker service includes 2 data repositories where your
> event data is stored:
>
> One repository where event data is available for analysis through
> Kibana. The standard or lite plan only stores data in this repository.
> Data is kept for 3 days.
>
> One long-term storage repository that hosts
> the event data for the premium plan. Event data is stored until you
> either configure a retention policy or delete them manually. By
> default, events are kept indefinitely.

The storage is encrypted. Also, to configure the retention policy read this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker/how-to/configuring_retention_policy.html#configuring_retention_policy)

Comment: This is paid? Is there free service? Plus it is not continuous, I need a permanent connection to push logs outside?

Comment: Yes, Premium is paid.  There is a Lite(free) plan but with limitations. You can find more information about the plans and what they offer here- https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker/activity_tracker_ov.html#activity_tracker_ov

Comment: Is there a way to continuously stream out data from paid plan?

Comment: Getting following error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, running above command.

Comment: @NoviceMe Updated my answer with details on where the Activity Tracker event data is stored.

Comment: Any command I run I get the 509 error. for example: ibmcloud at session create -s 2018-11-21 -e 2018-11-22 --json

Comment: I am expecting that you are running this on an Activity Tracker service created under Premium plan? If so check run this command to see the status of your Activity tracker(at) `ibmcloud at status`

Comment: Same thing, maybe proxies, will try later. Also, can I use this in a script somehow to continuously spit data out?

Comment: Yes, you can write a script or a polling job to periodically pull the events data to store in a storage like Cloud Object Storage or JSON on Cloudant NoSQL DB.

Comment: I was able to get the logs out. But the question still remains how can I poll continuously? As currently, it polls only during a particular date. I want continuous polling like every 5 minutes or so for new data coming in?

Comment: This is what I use for polling - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_feeds.html#openwhisk_feeds. It comes with a corn job which you can configure. As data is persistent for 3 days you can do a pull every three days or do it every minute.

Comment: @NoviceMe FYI...IBM Log Analysis with LogDNA is available today on IBM Cloud. This service simplifies log management in the Cloud and provides a setting for long-term archiving to IBM Cloud Object Storage - Read more here -https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/11/increase-observability-ibm-log-analysis-with-logdna-is-available-today-on-ibm-cloud/

Comment: U were saying that you are running a cron job to pull data out of AT. Can you please share code or do you have it anywhere on git?

Comment: @NoviceMe I tried with Serverless approach but as sometimes the file is too large, serverless is not a good option here. So, I created a Cloud Object Storage service and created a NodeJS app which when you run will generate events and create an object in COS bucket. You can find the code here - https://repl.it/@aficionado/ActivityTrackerCloudObjectStorage . Follow the comments in the code

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way in IBM to send audit logs out  in JSON? Like something that pushes out logs as they come rather than pulling?

Comment: As mentioned above, you can use LogDNA(released recently) with log analysis service where there is an option to easily archive logs to Cloud Object Storage - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA/archive.html#archiving

Comment: This does not make sense at all. The code you are suggesting above is not exporting data continuously. I have to wait for a day to export data. If I use the code you send above and poll for data every 5 minutes, I will have all duplicate data??